# What happens if you don't free dynamically allocated memory in a function?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I am learning how to write functions in C to accept an array and return a modified array.

In function `testfunc` (which is supposed to simply add `10` to each element of input array `b`) I am allocating memory for `npts` number of integers using `malloc`. But since I want to return this array using a pointer, I am not freeing this memory at the end of the function. Suppose I call this function `100` times like I am doing in the code, so what happens to the all the memory allocated during the code ? Is the amount of memory used by the code `100*10*4` bytes ? For a function which doesn't work on dynamic memory allocation, I think memory allocated to variables disappears when the function returns the final value and when it is called again, it again allocates memory and so on. But I am confused as to what happens in this case.

i cannot free the allocated memory inside the function since i need it to return the array to the main function, but also i need to call this function more than 100 times for different arrays, so if it keeps on allocating again and again, it will run out of memory

And is there a way to check how much memory a code is using ? (other than looking at Activity Monitor on Mac-OSX).

Thanks !

```
/* code to test returning array from functions */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int* testfunc(int *a,int npts);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int *b;
    int a[10],i,j,npts=10;

    b=(int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*npts);

    for (j=0; j <100; j++)
    {
        printf("iteration number %d \n",j);
        for (i=0; i<npts; i++)
        {
            a[i]=i;
            printf("%d \n",a[i]);
        }

        b=testfunc(a,npts);

        printf("returned array \n");
        for (i=0; i<npts; i++)
        {
            printf("%d \n",b[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("the size of one integer is %d \n",sizeof(int));

    return 0;
}
int* testfunc(int *b,int npts)
{
    int *c;
    int i=0;

    c=(int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*npts);

    for (i=0; i<npts; i++)
    {
        c[i]=b[i]+10;
    }

    return c;
}
```

---

This is the possible solution to avoid allocating memory inside a function and being able to call the function multiple times

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void testfunc(int *c,int *d,int npts);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int *a,*b;
    int i,j,npts=10;

    a=malloc(sizeof(int)*npts);
    b=malloc(sizeof(int)*npts);

    for (j=0; j <100; j++)
    {
        printf("iteration number %d \n",j);
        for (i=0; i<npts; i++)
        {
            a[i]=i;
            printf("%d \n",a[i]);
        }

        testfunc(a,b,npts);

        printf("returned array \n");
        for (i=0; i<npts; i++)
        {
            printf("%d \n",b[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("the size of one integer is %d \n",sizeof(int));

    free(a);
    free(b);

    return 0;
}
void testfunc(int *c,int *d,int npts)
{
    int i=0;

    for (i=0; i<npts; i++)
    {
        d[i]=c[i]+10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
c=(int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*npts);
:
return c;
```

This passes back both the memory *and* the responsibility for managing it.

It has become the responsibility of the caller (`main` in this cae) to free it when finished.

Where your real problem lies is here in `main`:

```
b=(int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*npts);
:
for (some number of iterations)
    b=testfunc(a,npts);  // overwrites b
```

On that "overwrites" line, you actually have a memory leak because you lose access to the memory currently allocated for `b` (both originally and in the prior iteration of the loop).

---

And, as an aside, please don't cast the return value of `malloc` in C. It's not needed and can hide certain subtle errors that you really *don't* want to have to debug :-)

Comment: so in that code, there are 100 memory leaks and all that memory is allocated but i cannot access it so it is being wasted ?

Comment: @Guddu: Yes, though it'll be let go automatically when the process exits. This isn't actually guaranteed by the standard but I've never seen an implementation that lets malloced memory hang around after process exit.

Comment: also regarding your answer `This passes back both the memory and the responsibility for managing it`, so if i free `b` in main function, does it automatically free `c` ?

Comment: @Guddu, c is a memory address in the function. By returning it, you set b to the same memory address. So yes, freeing b is freeing c or (more technically correct) you're freeing the memory block behind b.

Comment: can you please check the workaround in my post and let me know if it is correct ? thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @Guddu, that looks all right in terms of allocation. You allocate both arrays once in `main`, use them many times (passing them to the function) and then free them.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using **malloc**, which means you are allocating memory from **heap** not **stack**.
You should firstly figure out the mechanism of heap and stack.In C,**malloc** will help programmer allocate memory from heap, the same as **new** in C++.
So even if the function return the final value, the memory allocated will not be freed.If you call the function 100 times, it will allocate memory for you 100 times.
And as for a tool, you can refer to **Valgrind**, which is a powerful tool to check whether there exists a memory error.

Answer (score 1):

It's main that have to free() the allocated space, but  you have to be sure that you don't modified the value on the space during the function.

Answer (score 0):

If dynamically allocated memory is not freed,  it results in a memory leak and system will run out of memory. This can lead to program crashing.

Answer (score -1):

hey objective of call by reference is to modify the input pointer and return back to caller. 
means modified values i.e address still with caller.

You can simply do modification without allocate memory in your function

Just correction in your second approach

void testfunc(int *c,int npts)
{
    int i=0;

```
for (i=0; i<npts; i++)
{
    c[i] += 10; //YOU JUST INCREMENT VALUE by 10 
}
```

}

My approach to write function:

1. no memory allocation
2. no multiple arguments
3. keep necessary input, output argument , return value
4. here  int *c, npts -- input argument, output [ your value modified in int *c location]